# Accessing a file dialog inside an iframe

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an inline jsp page which has the code for the  html type: file. The below displayed IFRAME tag is in the main jsp. I want to pass on the file name and submit this file dialog using the web driver. Basically want to do something like:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("attachmentfile"));        
elem.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg");
```

However, am not able to get a hold of the attachmentfile id. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Main Jsp:

```
<IFRAME id=fileupload src="fileupload.jsp?type=uploadbutton"
frameBorder=0></IFRAME></TD></TR></FORM>
```

The fileupload.jsp is as below:

```
    <html> <body>
    <form name="frm_fileUpload" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"><%
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="attachmentfile" 
        id="attachmentfile" onChange="uploadFile   ();" />
        <input type="button" name="uploadbutton" id="uploadbutton" 
        value="Upload" class="button" />
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </form>                
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I switched to the frame fileupload. However, the attachmentfile id is not displayed. It is enabled and present, but not displayed. So, when I do: driver.findElement(By.id("attachmentfile")).sendKeys("C:\\Image.jpg"), it gives Element not visible exception.

Comment: Not sure if this is a case of this feature  not supported on IE.

Comment: The driver does not interact with elements that are not displayed on all browsers.

Comment: How about trying this ?((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById("attachmentfile").value="filename")"

Comment: @A.J You can't change the value of `<input type='file' />` elements via JavaScript. It's a security thing. Otherwise, websites could simply upload all your PC's content on the web.

Comment: @cooler8020002000 If it's not displayed, then you can't upload to it using `WebDriver`. Or is it displayed to normal human eye? Did you try it with Firefox, too?

Comment: @Slanec You are right, that's a security thing with js. The dialog gets displayed to the normal human eye. However, the driver is not able to detect the file type element. Cannot try it with firefox yet, since the app does not support firefox.

Comment: @cooler8020002000 Huh. Seems like a really annoying thing for no reason. I guess the unclosed jsp `<%` on line 2 is just a copy+paste artefact, right? Can you select anything other in the iframe? Like the parent `td`? If yes, then ... the best thing I can think of is to click the `td` and then blidly input the filename with [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). I wonder what would happen if you tried to `sendKeys` to the td, too. Soo many questions :).

Comment: Seems like this is a know issue with IE8,9: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3858#makechanges